# ng-class not evaluating expression in simple example

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

This code is inside ng-repeat loop.  The expression is not evaluating inside browser and the entire statement is their in browser also.

```
 <i ng-class="'icon-ok' : student.is_passed == 'passed', 'icon-remove': student.is_passed == 'failed'"></i>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put your expression inside curly braces `"{}"`

```
<i ng-class="{'icon-ok' : (student.is_passed == 'passed'), 'icon-remove': (student.is_passed == 'failed')}"></i>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me on IE. In Chrome is just fine. :(